# Как вставить из буфера обмена текст в переменную C#?

Tags: c#

Скрипт копирует текст и заносит его в буфер обмена. Как в С# потом вставить текст, который находится в буфере обмена, в переменную?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/kz40084e(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй вот это:

```
Clipboard.GetText
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/kz40084e(v=vs.110).aspx